# I created a Power Automate flow to add members to an Office 365 Group. My run history shows the run succeeded but all of the members weren't added

Tags: power-automate, office-365-groups

I've included a screenshot of the flow I created. The first image is Actions 1 & 2 & partial 3 and the second image is the end of Acton 3

[image: Power Automate Flow - Actions 1, 2 & partial 3]

[image: Power Automate Flow - end of Action 3]